# Merge colliders of different gameobjects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create an auto spawned of game object out of predefined prefab.

The prefab contains a polygon collider.

The spawned instantiates the new object right at the end of the previous one, in a way that it looks like a single piece.

I'm trying to understand how to merge both of their colliders to be like a single polygon collider defined on the merged object.

Thank you for helping.

Btw if there's a code involved (which I'm sure there is), I would be glad if you could write it in c#.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

So from reading your Q and information provided i would say that you want one polygon collider to be exactly on the other. If this is your goal, when they collide, you can us the transform function and move it to the exact position of the other.

Comment: That's a nice idea but those game objects are different in their shape.  What do you recommend? Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: so what exactly do u want to do? change the shape of the colliding object to the object it is hiting and move it to the position?

Comment: That's an option yeah.

Comment: okay so please explain to me what your gameobject is? is it an image are you using 3D ;2D. because in order to change the shape you would need a prefab of how you want the gameobject to look and then basicly switch the gameobject

Comment: It's a 2D game. The game objects are prefabs created out of images. They look like tunnels.

Comment: well in this instance you should change the shape of the colliding gameobject in i'm guessing photoshop and use the "switch and case" statement to change the prefabs.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand you. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I'm trying to build a long road out of small parts that each have polygon collider on it. The problem is that I once there are couple of parts connected I want the collider on them to be merged.

Comment: well therefore all you need to do is when the two collide you create a new polygon collider and set to fit o the 2 colliders

Comment: How can I do that on runtime?

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/69392/make-game-like-jetpack-joyride-unity-2d-part-1 this may have some help where it comes to the basic idea u want

Comment: Would you know any other way of doing this maybe?